# Why RiveRuntime module is causing error every time I open Xcode project

Tags: xcode, swiftui, rive

Every time I open an existing swiftUI app which includes Rive animations it is saying no module named RiveRuntime. I have to create the project all over again to make it run.
Please give me a solution to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because xcode is not able to fetch the framework everytime. You can download the framework and in the project settings choose the downloaded framework which works well without internet.